# How do I improve my script for dragging multiple cells in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I have a google script here which sends rows from one sheet to another then deletes the source row depending on a cell value. The aim is to send old tasks to a separate spreadsheet (i.e. from the 'task list' tab to the 'archived task list' tab) to stop overcrowding in one sheet.

The code I have works successfully when I change the status (column 5) to "Archive" however when I try to change multiple rows at once (i.e. drag down or copy), the script only works for the one row. I think I have to create some sort of loop to stop this problem but I am new to scripts so any help on this would be great!

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Task List
  // target sheet of move to named Archive Task List
  // test column with "Archive" is col5
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Task List" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "Archive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive Task List");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
I have implemented the code changes suggested and the script still works fine for single row edits, however if I do 2 or more edits at once the loop is archiving some rows out of the selected range. An example would be that if I copy cells F16:F19 all with entries "Archive" and paste into col5.
My updated code is:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Task List
  // target sheet of move to named Archive Task List
  // test column with "Archive" is col5 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Task List" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "Archive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var lastRow = r.getLastRow(); //Save the last edited row index
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var numRows = lastRow - row == 0? 1: lastRow - row; // numRows has to be at least 1 =, this is in case of a single-line row.
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive Task List");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    //s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Take in account the lastRow when archiving the edited range.     
    //s.deleteRow(row);
    for (let i = row; i<=lastRow; i++) {
      s.deleteRow(i);
      console.log(`Deleted row ${i}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Consideration

In your current script you are working only with the first row of the edited range:
`var row = r.getRow();`. That's why it will take only the first row of a multi-lines  edited range. To overcome this issue you should take in account the last row of the edited range, you can get it easily using  `var lastRow = r.getLastRow();`.

Keeping this in mind I would suggest these modifications to your script:

### Solution

1st:

```
   var row = r.getRow();
   var lastRow = r.getLastRow(); //Save the last edited row index
```

2nd (edited):

Correct syntax for getting the whole edited rows: `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`

```
    var numRows = lastRow-row + 1; // Corrected this calculation
    s.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Take in account the lastRow when archiving the edited range.
```

3rd (edited):

Deleting all the archived rows:

```
for (let i = row; i<=lastRow; i++) {
      s.deleteRow(row); // The row deletion will slide up all the other rows so the next row to delete will have always the same index
      console.log(`Deleted row ${row} at pass number ${i}`);
    }
```

This is a loop operation that loops the rows in the edited range.

### References

[getRange(row,col,numRow,numCol)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

[for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: I have implemented the code changes you've suggested and the script still works fine for single row edits, however if I do 2 or more edits at once the loop is archiving some rows out of the selected range - any ideas why or how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please update your question with an example on how you are editing the cells and your updated code.

Comment: I see, sorry I made a mistake. Please see my updated answer.